# How to correctly split an column into several columns in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to divide a column into several columns and what I am apparently doing is dividing it by rows, or rather by specifying how many rows "I want" per column, if anyone can help me, I would appreciate it

And here I will let you see my code:

```js
$(function($) {
    var num_cols = 4,
    container = $('.split-list'),
    listItem = 'td',
    listClass = 'sub-list';
    container.each(function() {
        var items_per_col = new Array(),
        items = $(this).find(listItem),
        min_items_per_col = Math.floor(items.length / num_cols),
        difference = items.length - (min_items_per_col * num_cols);
        for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
            if (i < difference) {
                items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col + 1;
            } else {
                items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
            $(this).append($('<ul></ul>').addClass(listClass));
            for (var j = 0; j < items_per_col[i]; j++) {
                var pointer = 0;
                for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                    pointer += items_per_col[k];
                }
                $(this).find('.' + listClass).last().append(items[j + pointer]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.split-list tr{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1em;
  
}
.split-list td{
  padding-right: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  @include font-size(12px);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="split-list">
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
  <td>list Item 1</td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by myself and I will publish the solution, if you ever guys have the same problem.

This is my code

```js
$(function($) {
    var num_cols = 4,
    container = $('.split-list'),
    listItem = 'tr',
    listClass = 'sub-list';
    container.each(function() {
        var items_per_col = new Array(),
        items = $(this).find(listItem),
        min_items_per_col = Math.floor(items.length / num_cols),
        difference = items.length - (min_items_per_col * num_cols);
        for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
            if (i < difference) {
                items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col + 1;
            } else {
                items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
            $(this).append($('<div class="col-3"></div>').addClass(listClass));
            for (var j = 0; j < items_per_col[i]; j++) {
                var pointer = 0;
                for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                    pointer += items_per_col[k];
                }
                $(this).find('.' + listClass).last().append(items[j + pointer]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Columnizer JQuery Plugin sample page</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Adam Wulf, Matt Wilson">
 <!-- Date: 2008-07-12 -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody class="split-list row">
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item num</td></tr>  
 
 
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```